# How to configure postfix Ubuntu with a tk domain

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, domain-name

I have a free my.tk domain and I want to send emails with it using postfix running on my Ubuntu server. Please look at the my.dot.tk website and post a step by step tutorial on how to configure postfix to send emails with the tk domain. Also, I want to send emails to websites like gmail and I want to connect this service with thunderbird.

Comment: First question is: do you have set mail exchanger to point your host as dot.tk domain. If no this will be against the rules of mail (send mail from account on which you can't receive mail)

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: On some host in dot.tk domain you should have MX record. And as this domain is not under you control you can't do this. Better think about domain from NoIP or similar